# xamarin Source vs MergeWith how to use it

Tags: xamarin.forms

quick question about ResourceDictionary.

In code I used to have this line of code

```
 Application.Current.Resources.MergedWith = typeof(myResourceDictionary);
```

apparently "MergeWith" is obsolete! and we should use "Source.

```
   Application.Current.Resources.Source = new Uri("myResourceDictionary.xaml");
```

However what i did above does not work.

How am I suppose to use source in code?

thanks

Answer (score -1):

If you use XAML, you can set like this:

```
 <ContentPage.Resources>

        <!-- Add more resources here -->

        <ResourceDictionary Source="MyResourceDictionary.xaml" />

        <!-- Add more resources here -->

    </ContentPage.Resources>
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply.I need to set in code.what is the equivalent?